# Hive 0.9, Hbase 0.98.5 and Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a single node Hadoop system. Installed version is 1.2.1. I have installed Hbase 0.98.5 and then I have installed Hive 0.9.

All the processes are running on my node.

Process details:

```
    [root@localhost /]# jps    
    24396 SecondaryNameNode    
    24152 NameNode    
    23954 Jps    
    24274 DataNode    
    24488 JobTracker    
    24607 TaskTracker    
    1282 HQuorumPeer     
    2429 HMaster
    2589 HRegionServer
```

From HBase shell, I am able to retrieve my table:

```
    --------Hbase Shell-----------------
    hbase(main):001:0> scan 'nancy'
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hbase-0.98.5-hadoop1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-                    1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-    1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    ROW                               COLUMN+CELL                                                                
    2                         column=cf:name, timestamp=1410461757734,        value=Test                        
    1 row(s) in 0.2220 seconds
```

I am also able to retrieve table list from Hive:

```
    ----------Hive Shell----------------------------------
    hive> SHOW TABLES;
    OK
    pokes
    Time taken: 3.195 seconds
```

I am able to create, populate tables in HBase and also in Hive. But I am unable to integrate Hive with Hbase.

When I am trying to register a table in Hive, I am getting the following error message:

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int,name string) STORED BY 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH 
      SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,cf:name") 
      TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="nancy");
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF        localhostï¿½ï¿½Éžï¿½Þ†)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

After following various websites on how to resolve the error, I have also done the following changes.

1. I have moved the hbase-clinet*.jar, hbase-server*.jar, hbase-common*.jar, hbase-protocol*.jar, hbase-common*.jar, zookeeper*.jar, guavae*.jar from $HBASE_HOME\lib to $HIVE\lib directory.
2. Copied the hbase configuration $HBASE_HOME\conf, hadoop configuration files from $HADOOP_HOME\conf to $HIVE_HOME\conf
3. Copied the hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar and hive-common-0.9.0.jar from $HIVE_HOME\lib to $HADOOP_HOME\lib and $HBASE_HOME\lib.

Kindly give me some information on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: I am unable to register Hbase tables using Hive

Comment: Hello Sir, Please let me know if I need to elaborate on this. I am struck on this for a quite of days.